# How to count the number of rows in condition?

Tags: mysql

I want to count the number of rows of a selected result.

E.g., SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE [the number of rows of a (SELECT QUERY)] = 1;

Answer (score 1):

you can use COUNT(*) to get the count from the table.

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sub_table) = 1 ;
```